# ID3 Unicode arabic characters php

Tags: php, unicode, arabic, id3

Im creating a audio library and i have a upload function. The upload function should read the ID3 tags to store it in the database. Since the sounds will be arabic tracks, the ID3 tags is in arabic and the function i have right now reads the tags but don't read the arabic tags, it returns "?????" i all arabic words/names. How can i encode it? What is the solution?

```
class CMP3File {
var $title;var $artist;var $album;var $year;var $comment;var $genre;
function getid3 ($file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $id_start=filesize($file)-128;
        $fp=fopen($file,"r");
        fseek($fp,$id_start);
        $tag=fread($fp,3);

        if ($tag == "TAG") {
            $this->title=fread($fp,30);
            $this->artist=fread($fp,30);
            $this->album=fread($fp,30);
            $this->year=fread($fp,4);
            $this->comment=fread($fp,30);
            $this->genre=fread($fp,1);
            fclose($fp);

            return true;
        } else {
            fclose($fp);
            return false;
        }
    } else { 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the exact byte values and post it here

Comment: I think this is the info you need http://i.imgur.com/3UlnLHB.png and http://i.imgur.com/mr2G6Zf.png @zerkms

Comment: @G unitzo: it's not. Instead of outputting data as as getting `?` - check what bytes you've received

Comment: Can you please explain how i can check it? @zerkms

Comment: `ord()` ...............

Comment: Sorry im not good at this. But i used Ord() and it returns 63 @zerkms

Comment: i used another function and it gives this values back ´Array ( [FileName] => ../files/819702.mp3 [TAG] => ID3 [Version] => 3.0 [Title] => ./'EC 3D'7JF [Album] => %5/'1 'D92) [Author] => #-E/ 'D9HJF'*J )´ @zerkms